# How to wait for didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to finish before handling universal link?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, ios-universal-links

In my Swift iOS app I asynchronously set up the initial view controller in the `AppDelegate` inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Now I'm adding a Universal Link such that if you go to the corresponding URL on your phone it will automatically open the right page in the app (in this case it's a password reset URL that, if correct, will open the password reset form inside the app).

I am handling the linking inside [`application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application) (`continueUserActivity`) in my `AppDelegate`.

It works if the app is already running but otherwise the link handling happens before my app has finished setting up the initial view controller and the view controller for the deep link gets dismissed when `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` returns.

How can I ensure the app is finished setting up before I present view controllers from `continueUserActivity`? I can't/shouldn't prevent `didFinishLaunching` from returning until the view controllers are set up, so the method returns before the initial view controller is presented.

I know I can check the user activity dictionary inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but `continueUserActivity` is still called (it would be much simpler if it was only called if the app was running, like how `didReceiveRemoteNotification` works). Is there a condition to check inside this method to defer the link handling to `didFinishLaunching`?

Some simplified `UIApplicationDelegate` code to help explain:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    doSomeAsyncSetup(
        completion: {
            presentSomeViewController()
        }
    )
    return true
}

func application(_: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler _: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
        let params = components.queryItems,
        components.path == pathThatIExpect
    {
            handleUniversalLink(params)
    }
    return true
}
```

Note there seems to be a slightly different distinction when the app has opted into `Scenes` but my app is not using that (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DispatchGroup` should be able to handle this for you.

```
private let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
    doSomeAsyncSetup(
        completion: {
            presentSomeViewController()
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    )
    return true
}

func application(_: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler _: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let url = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true),
        let params = components.queryItems,
        components.path == pathThatIExpect
    {
            self.dispatchGroup.notify {
                handleUniversalLink(params)
            }
    }
    return true
}
```

In the case where your app is being launched, the dispatch group is entered in `didFinishLaunching` and it is left once the view controller is presented.
Once the dispatch group is empty, the [`notify`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/2016066-notify) will execute the user activity code; so only after your view controller is presented.

In the case where your app is already launched, the dispatch group will be empty since `didFinishLaunching` isn't called and so the `notify` will execute immediately

Answer (score 0):

You can use serial queue for that. For example:

```
serialQueue.async {
    self.presentSomeViewController()
}
```

And

```
serialQueue.async {
    self.handleUniversalLink(params)
}
```

Comment: Task 2 will be started only after `didFinishLaunching`, so it will be the easiest way to fix that.

Comment: Think you just left out that you need an instance variable referencing the `serialQueue` like `let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "someLabel")`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't really work here because it needs to wait for async work to finish in `doSomeAsyncSetup`